# Getting no array key

Tags: php, foreach, array-key

Hey I'm trying to get the key of my array in a foreach.
But got this error
Warning:  array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given on line 10

***Here is my array:***

```
$status_de = array
(
    '1' => 'Anfrage',
    '2' => 'Angebot',
    '3' => 'Abgeschlossen'  
);
```

***Here is my code:***

```
<select name="land">
    <?php foreach ($status_de as $status) {
      echo "<option value='" . array_keys($status) . "'>" . $status . "</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use:

```
<?php foreach ($status_de as $key=>$status) {
  echo "<option value='" . $key . "'>" . $status . "</option>";
}
?>
```

as `array_keys()` will return **array** containing *all* keys (so not applicable to use with strings operators)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**foreach loop** will get key and value pair, so you can directly use it. No need any function to get those.

```
<select name="land">
    <?php foreach ($status_de as $key => $value) {
      echo "<option value='" . $key . "'>" . $value . "</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Pl accept answer, So others will get help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do like this because [`array_keys`](https://www.php.net/array_keys) expected an array. In your scenario you give a string.

try like this:

```
<select name="land">
    <?php foreach ($status_de as $k =>$v) {
      echo "<option value='" . $k . "'>" . $v . "</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
```